# RailsTutorial Sessions: Sign In doesn't flash success and sign out causes routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Following Hartl's railtutorial. When I try to log in, it takes me to the correct page, but "Successful login!" does not flash on the interface. Also, when I try to sign out, I get a Routing Error: `No route matches [GET] "/sessions/1"`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my sessions_controller.rb:

class SessionsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
  @title = "Log in"
end

def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], 
                           params[:session [:password])     
  if user.nil?
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
    @title = "Sign in"
    render 'new'
  else
    flash[:success] = "Successful login!"
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or user
  end
end

def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_path
end

end
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  #resources :users    this is the line I removed to get my code to work
  resource :user #this is the lined I added to get my code to work

  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]   


  match '/sessions', :to => 'users#show'
  match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
  match '/login', :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

  root :to => 'pages#home'
```

Changing `resources :users` to `resource :user` seems to allow me to "sign in" and "sign out" except that the flash success still does not appear on the user interface. This leads me to believe that there is an error in my create method.

Here is my sessions_helper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  self.current_user = user
end


def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end

def sign_out
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  self.current_user = nil
end

def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  clear_return_to
end

private

def user_from_remember_token
  User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
end

def remember_token
  cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
end

def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end

def clear_return_to
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
end
```

**Edited: Solution posted in code.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should user just `flash[:success]` and `flash[:error]` and not the `flash.now`

and what link are you using for loging out?

Comment: I'll try that. I'm using the destroy method. I'll post the sessions helper right now.

Comment: flash[:success] works! Do you know why I have to use 'resource :user' instead of 'resources :users'?

Comment: aren't helpers just for the view? i guess you should move all your methods over to application controller...

Comment: not quite sure; I'm still new to this. I'm just following Hartl's tutorial. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:sessions_controller

Comment: you dont have to - there is a huge difference between `resource :user` and `resources :users`
`resource :user` assumes that you are just managing one user at the time - it will just create routes for the new, create, edit, update, show and delete methodes.
`resources :user` assumes that you are have several users - so it creates also a route for the index method which is listing all users. so unless you want to provide a list of users to your current user user `resource :user`

Comment: and i am sorry, i was wrong - you have to use `flash.now` when you use `render`. so if the login fails you have to use `flash.now` there

Comment: ok, looked it up. its correct with the session helper because you include it in application controller. but your logout link should be this:

`<%= link_to "Sign out", logout_path, :method => :delete %>`

(use logout_path as you defined in your routes and not signout as in the tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; starting to make sense now. This is the link to logging out: `<%= link_to image_tag("logout_button.png", :alt => "Log Out", :class => "round", :mouseover => "logout_button_hover.png"), {:action => 'destroy', :controller => 'sessions'} %>`. Everything worked once I started using `resource :user` Thanks again for the help, Klump. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I just realised that I needed `resources :users` as well to load up my home page (which has a user sign up form). Insights?

Comment: what do you mean? what is your home page? what are you doing in the homepages' controller?

Comment: I put the user sign up form on my home page.

Comment: i guess you have somewhere used `users_path` or `users_url` (new user view or controller). when you just have `resource :user` this is not available and causing an error. btw: it would be nice if you could provide some error messages along - because its quite hard to always guess right :P